# Add an Event to Google Calender by Sending an Email

Tags: gmail, google-calendar

Is there any way to add an event to my Google Calendar by sending an email somewhere?

To be clear, I want the event to be created by the simple act of sending the email, I do not want to have to login to my Gmail account and click the "Add Event" button in the email or have to access the calendar directly.  Is there any built in functionality for this that I'm missing or any third party services that will allow this?

Also, I am aware of the SMS option (GVENT) but this isn't what I'm looking for.

Comment: What happens if you email yourself an iCal meeting?

Comment: Remember the Milk has a feature like this, and you can create tasks with a specific time. There is a RTM widget for GCal. What if you used that and mailed the event as a task to RTM? Not ideal, but maybe worth a shot.

Comment: I'm not sure what an iCal Meeting is.  Also, I use Toodledo instead of RTM and it actually inserts time set tasks into the calendar.  I should check and see if I can email myself tasks.  I think I can.  Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, it should exist the posibility of sending an email to paulexample+calendar@gmail.com with title event in subject and time range in message, or such.
Should be a lab working on this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I read your question and thought this sounded like something I would use, so I created a service that does it:

http://www.myeventbot.com/

I'd welcome your feedback!

Comment: Awesome, thanks!  I will check it out shortly.

Comment: 2 years, and still awesome! That would be great if the service was able to parse email body in order to let us add full events.

Comment: to bad this service doesn't work anymore

Answer (score 3):

Remember the milk offers the feature of [adding events via email](http://www.rememberthemilk.com/help/answers/sending/emailinbox.rtm). It also allows you to integrate the events in Google calendar. Hence I guess you can create a RTM Account and then keep emailing your calendar events to that mail address to appear on your GCal!

Answer (score 1):

If there is something that looks like an event in an e-mail message you receive, you'll get an "Add to Calendar" option in the right sidebar in Gmail.

For instance, I just sent a message to myself with the text "Let’s have lunch noon tomorrow" and I have an option to add a calendar event called "lunch" schedule for 12 noon local time. Two clicks and I'm done.

As for sending e-mail and getting it auto-added to your calendar, there doesn't appear to be a way to do that. That's probably a good thing; can you imagine what your calendar looked like if spammers got your address?

Comment: Thanks Al, but as I'm really looking to get around every having to login to gmail or google altogether.   Yes, it would be bad if spammers ever got the calendar email but it could be similar to how wordpress handles "posting by email" or how Evernote handles notes by email with a changeable "receiving" address.

Comment: Sure, I get that. As it stands there isn't a way to do it with Google Calendar as-is. I'm sure someone could build an app to use the Calendar API, but if one already exists I haven't found it.

Comment: If it's any consolation, you're not the only person who is looking for something like this.

Comment: Any update to this? Airlines are able to do it by sending me an itinerary; my SMS+ backup app from mobile phone is able to do it with my phone call log. Someone must have published a hack for it by now.

Comment: @J.Won.: No, not really. Gmail will add some things to your calendar automatically (travel iteneraries, for instance) if you allow it to do so, but there's still no generic way to send email to get something added to your Google Calendar without further interaction. Emailing an `ics` file comes close, if you allow events you've not RSVP'd to to appear on your calendar.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. There's no built in functionality. However, there's a third-party service that allows you to do just that:

> https://fut.email

Here's how it works:

1. You sign up with your Google account
2. You're asked to give OAuth access to your Google Calendar
3. Now you can send emails to `tomorrow@fut.email` to create events in your calendar.

Many other patterns work, such as time periods (`1mo@fut.email`), days of the week (`monday@fut.email`), and specific dates (`20210704@fut.email`).

There's a free trial.

---

Discloure: I'm the maker (so any feedback is greatly appreciated)

Comment: Your answer was sent automactically to th elow question review queeue because it's lenght and content. I suggest you to be a bit more descriptive about what your service does.

Comment: Good point, thanks!